# C# link write fault (html)

Tags: c#, html, wordpress, hyperlink

I write a small program in c# which is send datas to a blog platform.

```
post.Body = postContent + "<br><img src=\"" + linkToImage + "\"  />";
```

This is working for me right, i got the result in my blog.:

```
<img src="http://*************.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ss.jpg" />
```

But i would like put after the ss.jpg the next.: style="display:none"

If i tried make this.:

```
post.Body = postContent + "<br><img src=\"" + linkToImage + "\" + "style="display:none"" />";
```

Its not working. ( would like hide the image.)

I need, the end result like this link.:

```
<img src="http://************/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ss.jpg" style="display:none"/>
```

Can somebody help me?

Thank you

Comment: Probably should add what "it's not working" means exactly -- it appears here that you're escaping double quotes incorrectly: `linkToImage + "\" + "style="display:none"" />"` You've got an extra `" + "` between the end `"` for your `src` attribute, perhaps? I suspect that's showing a syntax error where you can't even compile, and if not and you're using in an uncompiled template, what's the **html code that's produced** -- Include the specifics of how it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no string interpolation required as style="display:none;" is being output as is - it is not dependant on any condition or variable in your code therefore this should work:

```
post.Body = postContent + "<br><img src=\"" + linkToImage + "\" style=\"display: none;\"  />";
```